# How do I add user defined custom fields to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-helpers, fields-for

In my blog application, I have a `post` model (`name:string, body:text`). I want to allow the user to define a `custom_field` (the model has name:string). This causes the `post` form to contain a text_field for that `custom_field`, and the value of that field should be returned as a param from create or update. The actual data returned is of model custom_field_instance (value:string custom_field:references post:references)

For example, if a user created a custom field with name **author**, and another custom field with name **email** then I want the post form to display an author and email text fields, and two custom field instances to be returned with the params (one for author, one for email).

The custom fields show up fine in the form, no problem. The params also look fine when there is a  single custom field.

The problem is that only one custom field's params are sent in the params. If there are multiple fields, then only the last one's data is sent.

Suppose I have an author and email custom field, and in the new post form, I set name as 'John Doe' and email as 'john@example.com', here is what I get in the params (only one custom field instance, the email one, which is the last one):

```
Parameters: 
{..., "post"=>{"title"=>"post2", ...}, 
  "custom_field_instances"=>
     {"value"=>"john@example.com", "custom_field_id"=>[email_custom_field_id]}, 
"commit"=>"Create Post"}
```

Here is what I expect to see in the params (both custom field instances :

```
Parameters: 
{..., "post"=>{"title"=>"post2", ...}, 
  "custom_field_instances"=> 
     {"value"=>"John Doe", "custom_field_id"=>[author_custom_field_id]},   
     {"value"=>"john@example.com", "custom_field_id"=>[email_custom_field_id]}, 
"commit"=>"Create Post"}
```

Here is the code that I have so far:

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @custom_fields = CustomField.all
end
```

**views/posts/new.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for @post,... %>
...
<% @custom_fields.each do |custom_field| %>
    <% @custom_field_instance = CustomFieldInstance.new %>
    <%= fields_for :custom_field_instances, @custom_field_instance do |custom_field_instance_fields| %>
        <%= custom_field_instance_fields.label custom_field.name %>
        <%= custom_field_instance_fields.text_field :value %>       
        <%= custom_field_instance_fields.hidden_field :custom_field_id, value: custom_field.id %>
    <% end %> <!-- end of fields_for block  -->
  <% end %> <!-- end of custom_fields.each loop  -->
...
<% end %> <!-- end of form_for block  -->
```

I have also tried without the `@custom_field_instance` where the `fields_for` line becomes `<%= fields_for :custom_field_instances do |custom_field_instance_fields| %>`, but it doesn't change anything (still the last custom field instance is the only one sent in the params).

**Update 1**: I also tried using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but then the view did not show the custom field text fields, since it seems like nested_attributes are only used for existing instances of the associated model. The changes are:

To the above code, I added `accepts_nested_attributes_for :custom_field_instances` to **item_instance.rb**, and in the view code above, replaced `fields_for ...` with `post_form.fields_for ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it as an `Array`

Not tested.

**try1:**

```
<%= custom_field_instance_fields.text_field, name: 'value[]' %>
```

or

```
<%= custom_field_instance_fields.text_field, 'value[]' %>
```

same for hidden field.

---

**try2:** ( worked for OP )

use `{:multiple => true}`

---

**try3:**

```
serialize :name, Array
```

in your `CustomFieldInstance` model

Comment: Thanks! try2 - `multiple: true` worked!  try1 - both options did not work, did not try try3. Could you please update the answer to reflect that try2 works, thanks.

Comment: It works for new, but in edit, the fields do not get prepopulated. Should I have separate code for new and edit (in edit case, I could, instead of the above, do `@post.custom_field_instances.each do ...`

Comment: ya may be different view, use `value` field .

Comment: Seems like the multiple attribute is not supported in earlier versions of browsers - is there a more rails-y way of doing this to work in older browsers as well?

Comment: browser compatible with rails, new thing I'm hearing to.

Comment: multiple attribute is an html 5 attribute, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp) - which is what `multiple: true` generates from rails in the view html

Comment: in `rails` multiple does 2 things, makes the name attribute to `Array` and adds `multiple` to the chosen tag.